# PgAdmin Connecting to Postgres through Docker-compose results in "Unable to connect to server : timeout expired"

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

Consider the Docker-compose :

```
version: "3"
services:
  postgres_svc:
    image: postgres:12.0-alpine
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: root
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: myCoolPassword
      POSTGRES_DB: postgres      
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"


   ... More services
```

When I run `Docker-compose up` and run :

```
docker inspect <POSTGRES_ID> | grep Gateway >>> 192.168.16.1
```

or

```
docker inspect <POSTGRES_ID>| grep IPAddress  >>> 192.168.16.3
```

I get the IP/Gateway of the postgres container , and then in **PGADMIN** :

[image]

[image]

And the same thing for the IP `192.168.16.3`.

How can we solve this connection problem ?

Comment: Ignore the `docker inspect` IP addresses, which don't work in many common scenarios.  Use `localhost` (usually) as the host name, and the first `ports:` number.

Comment: (Or if pgadmin is in the same Compose file, the service name `postgres_svc` and the standard PostgreSQL port 5432, ignoring `ports:`.)

Comment: @DavidMaze: You're a goddamn genius ,I've added a `pgadmin` service and it worked fine with calling `postgres_svc` as the host. Please post your answer officially and I'll accept it!

Comment: Both variants on this are described in the linked question (along with several `docker inspect`-based options).

Comment: @DavidMaze: It's close but not really , the trick was to add a new Service to Docker-compose : a `pgAdmin` service , and then and only then , the host `postgres_svc` would be identified by its name , without using any IP/Gateway of any other lie.Thanks a lot!